# Magento payment method with third party gateway

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway, payment

In the checkout process of Magento, I use only the credit card method. In the last step, I need to send all the information collected to an external url at my payment gateway.

All the data is processed by the third party gateway, then redirects to my Magento website with the result of the operation.

What should I do to achieve this? Where should I start to look? Do i need to modify the magento payment module code?

Comment: Who is your payment processor? What payment processing product are you using?

Comment: Note, you need "PCI-DSS" compliance if you are handling credit card data in any way, even inf you are not storing it.

Comment: Who is your payment processor? e-Com Banamex,if you refer to the bank or company that is going to process the data, i'm new in this of payment process, What payment processing product are you using?, don;t understend this one, can you explain me?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create your own payment method.
What kind of gateway you will use?

Comment: What kind of gateway you will use? -- ssl?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PayPal Pro (directly payment), The PayPal will get the authorization and send the money to your PayPal account.